# Java Gson List - How to access individual items

Tags: java, gson

I have the following class:

```
class Person 
{
    String Name; 
}
```

I read in the following Json data:

```
{
    "People": [{
            "Name": "Test"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

I do this using a generic class as these could be students, professors etc..

```
public BusinessData<T> GetDataFromJson(String Url)
{
    // Get the data from the URL 
    return new Gson().fromJson(data, new TypeToken<BusinessData<T>>(){}.getType());
}

public List<People> GetPeople()
{
      return this.GetDataFromJson(Url).People;
}
```

Therefore.. I should now have a `List` of the class `People`.. However, whenever I try and do the following:

```
for(People person : PeopleList)
{
    System.out.println(person.getName());  
}
```

I get the following error:

```
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.proj.business.Models.Person
```

Which to me makes no sense, because:

1. I pass in `List<People>` to the method I'm trying to use the data with just fine
2. If I just do a standard `System.out.println(people.get(1))` then the data is printed out just fine in the class `Person`

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This `new TypeToken<BusinessData<T>>(){}.getType()` will never work. See the duplicate for an explanation as to why, and a potential solution.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is you are getting an array of People, first cast from Array to List

Comment: Please can you give an example? I'm not too sure what you mean

Answer (score -1):

here:

```
public class Test {


    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        Person personA = new Person("David");
        Person personb = new Person("Pedro");

        Person[] arrayPeople = {personA, personb};
        List<Person> listPeople = Arrays.asList(arrayPeople);
        for(Person x: listPeople)
            System.out.println(x.getName());


    }





}

class Person{
    private String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Person() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: hope this help you

Comment: I am confused. I already have a `List<Person>` which contains an array of `Person` from a json array?

Comment: yes, you just need to cast